# Share with facebook and successful callback

Tags: javascript, facebook

first of all sorry for my poor english.

Title probably explain what im asking for, now i know how to do this by load

```
facebook-jssdk, 
then window.fbAsyncInit and FB.init, 
and lastly using FB.ui( {}, function( response ) {} );
```

unfortunately, what im trying to do is, use that as a widget on few other pages diffrent than the main APP Url, and no, i don't want to do this by adding those domains to app.

Is there any other way? Keep in mind that i want to get the info when user actually share something. I'll be glad for some examples.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what for you you want to know if the user shared something?

Comment: is that important? I simply want to know and track if user share or feed from that particular widget and page and react for that action

Comment: it´s actually pretty important, because you are not allowed to incentivize sharing. that´s why facebook made it extra-hard to track.

Comment: Ok, extra-hard doesn't mean impossible, so do you have any tip ?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik it´s not possible at all to check if the user shared something with FB.ui share anymore, just check the response value with console.log. There is one solution by authorizing the user with `publish_actions`, but you will not get that one approved just for tracking if he shared something. In that case, the response will be the id of the entry:

> Only available if the user is logged into your app using Facebook and has granted publish_actions. If present, this is the ID of the published Open Graph story.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog